# xcode copy array position to another array

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, nsarray

Probably is a basic issue but I am trying to set an array objectAtIndex from another array and following gives an error. Thanks for help.

```
[self.appUrl objectAtIndex: 0] = [self.appCell objectAtIndex: 1];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSArray's are not mutable. If you want to change an object you can;

```
NSMutableArray *arrayCopy = [originalArray mutableCopy];
[arrayCopy replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:newObject];
//assign the changed copy to the original variable name.
originalArray = arrayCopy;
```

So:

```
[self.appUrl objectAtIndex: 0] = [self.appCell objectAtIndex: 1];
```

Is:

```
NSMutableArray *copy = [self.appUrl mutableCopy];
[copy replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[self.appCell objectAtIndex:1]];
[self.appUrl mutableCopy];
```

Or simply declare your Array as mutable:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *appUrl;
```

Comment: I did it and does not give any compiling errors but when I execute it, crashes returning EXC_BAD_ACCES.  [self.appUrl replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[self.appCell objectAtIndex: 1]];

Comment: Yeah, sorry. If there are no objects you can't replace any you just use addObject:.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare array as mutable and then call replaceObjectAtIndex:WithObject